# How to call EnumSystemLocales() in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How to call EnumSystemLocales() function in C++ within the same class? My callback function is :

```
BOOL CALLBACK CLanguage::EnumLocalesProc(LPWSTR lpLocaleString) {

    RETAILMSG(TRUE, (L"[GUI] LOCALE: %s!\n\r", lpLocaleString));

    return TRUE;

}
```

Calling `EnumSystemLocales(&CLanguage::EnumLocalesProc, LCID_INSTALLED)` does not work!

**Edit:**
It is Windows Embedded Compact 7. And the error is in syntax:

> Error 2   error C2664: 'EnumSystemLocalesW' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'BOOL (__cdecl CLanguage::* )(LPWSTR)' to 'LOCALE_ENUMPROCW'
>   {log="C:\WINCE700\osdesigns\UVVIS2\UVVIS2\GUI\bldsys.log(32)"}    c:\wince700\osdesigns\uvvis2\uvvis2\gui\clanguage.cpp   24

Comment: are all of them declared public ???

Comment: Everything here is decalred as public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MSalters pointed out, `BOOL (__cdecl CLanguage::* )(LPWSTR)` is a pointer to a member function and does not match the required signature for `LOCALE_ENUMPROCW`.

Since the program has no idea which ***instance** of the `CLanguage` class* your method belongs to, it can't rightly call it when it needs to. Most APIs will try to resolve this by allowing an additional `void*` argument to be passed, which can point to said class.

You need to move your `EnumLocalesProc` function out of the `CLanguage` class. If you want to retain the scoping for organization, try moving the callback into a *namespace*.

```
namespace CApiInterface
{
    BOOL CALLBACK EnumLocalesProc(LPWSTR lpLocaleString) {...}
}

// Register callback. Note that address of (&) operator is not required.
EnumSystemLocales(CApiInterface::EnumLocalesProc, LCID_INSTALLED)
```

The fact that you need to access other *member variables* of a class during the `EnumLocalesProc` function is what makes it difficult. There are other ways to handle this case.

You could try making a **Singleton** handler class?

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumLocalesProc(LPWSTR lpLocaleString) 
{
    return CLanguage::GetInstance().EnumLocalesProc(lpLocaleString);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I didn't say that it is Windows Embedded Compact 7 - sorry about that. In my case it has to be LPWSTR.

Comment: EnumSystemLocales() is automatically changed to EnumSystemLocalesW() anyway so it brings no change... (I tried anyway).

Comment: You're right. I've completely re-written my answer so these comments are now obsolete.

Comment: Well, I cannot create namespace "CLanguage" (outside of class definition), because I get an error: "Error 2 error C2757: 'CLanguage' : a symbol with this name already exists and therefore this name cannot be used as a namespace name"...

Comment: Yeah ok, then name it something else. See my changes. The point is you need to supply something that **isn't a member method**

Comment: Yes, thank you it works! At the beginning I also tried to change the namespace name, but it didn't work, because it was defined in CLanguage.h. When moved to CLanguage.cpp, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that the C API doesn't support pointers to member functions `(CLanguage::*)`

Comment: True. I included `EnumLocaledProc` in a namespace `CLanguage`, which might be a better approach for the OP to get code organized.

Comment: @Aesthete: The error message strongly suggests that `CLanguage` is `class CLanguage { }`, not `namespace CLanguage { }`, as does your remark about `public`.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. That's why I said it **might be a better approach**.

Comment: The function can't be a member function, as @MSalters mentioned. Is there a specific reason it needs to be a member function?

Comment: No, it is only to keep data organized.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR>> tLocales;
std::vector<std::basic_string<TCHAR>> g_locales;

BOOL CALLBACK MyLocaleEnumProc(LPTSTR szLocaleString)
{
  g_locales.push_back(szLocaleString);
  return TRUE;
}
int _tmain()
{
 // Get all locales
  EnumSystemLocales(&MyLocaleEnumProc, LCID_INSTALLED);

 // Print out all locales
for(tLocales::const_iterator i=g_locales.begin(); i != g_locales.end(); i++)
{
   _tprintf(_T("Locale: %s\r\n"), i->c_str());
}
 return 0;
}
```